# LoadUserProfile in a loop

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# and am updating the code of another programmer. I see this code for loading the users from a remote server :

```
var userProfileLoaded = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
  {
    if (i > 0)
      await Task.Delay(50);

    if (LoadUserProfile(phUserToken, ref lpProfileInfo))
    {
      userProfileLoaded = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

LoadUserProfile seems to be synchronous function. So if it fails, the loop is a non-sense right ? Since the program is taking a lot of time and getting a timeout for IIS timeout, and since it takes 1.5 seconds every time the LoadUserProfile fails, then I guess I can save time here to write this function better and avoid the await if in fact there would be no need to do so. If it is asnychronouse, I must change to await (LoadUserProfile...) ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the definition of `LoadUserProfile`? Is this a `DllImport`-ed function? Why is it calling this function? There's probably a better way to solve the original problem that prompted this (and ideally, IIS Worker Processes should never need to load their profile data anyway) - I'm assuming this has to do with loading the certificate store?

Comment: If your worker-process needs to load the profile for the certificate store, try using the Application Pool's configuration in IIS Manager instead: there's an option to load the profile with the pool so you don't need to do it in-proc - if that works then you can remove this code entirely.

Comment: This would appear to be an entirely ridiculous way to prevent having to set the IIS option "Load user profile" on the application pool. Just do the latter and dump this code. But we don't know the context, nor why this is there, nor why the original developer thought calling it 30 times is a good idea, so we don't know what will break when you do so.

Comment: @CodeCaster Indeed. It's also going to break horribly if there's any dependence on the current `Thread` identity, because `await Task.Delay` is not guaranteed to return on the same thread - and don't forget all the fun with `HttpContext.Current` being unsafe.